# Query name of the most expensive product that each manufacturer has and its price

Tags: mysql, sql

Returns a list with the name of the most expensive product that each manufacturer has. The result should have three columns: product name, price, and manufacturer name. The result must be ordered alphabetically from lowest to highest by the manufacturer's name.

database

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tienda;
CREATE DATABASE tienda CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE tienda;

CREATE TABLE fabricante (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  codigo_fabricante INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(codigo)
);

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

This is the query I am trying to do:

```
SELECT p.nombre as 'Product name', MAX(p.precio) as 'price', f.nombre as 'manufacturer name'
FROM fabricante f LEFT JOIN producto p ON f.codigo = p.codigo_fabricante
GROUP BY f.nombre
ORDER BY f.nombre;
```

The problem I have with this query is that the name of the product does not correspond to the price column, the product price and manufacturer name columns do show them correctly. I have tried to make several subqueries but I cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NOT EXISTS in WHERE clause like below

```
select 
F.nombre,
P.nombre,
P.precio
from fabricante  F
join producto P
on F.codigo=p.codigo_fabricante
where not exists 
(
select 1 from producto P2
where P2.codigo_fabricante=F.codigo
and P2.precio>P1.precio
and P2.codigo <>P1.codigo
)
```